# Now I have duplicate emails lists name

Tags: php

I have a TXT file with a list of emails
Now I have duplicate emails lists name
Example:

```
sami@woo.com
sds@woo.com
sami@woo.com
asfi@woo.com
sami@woo.com
```

I want to show me only once every mail

And the result:

```
sami@woo.com
sds@woo.com
asfi@woo.com
```

This code that I would love to get help:

```
<? Php

$ Username = $ argv [1];
$ File = file_get_contents (". / Emailist.txt");
$ Ex = explode ("\ r \ n", $ file);
for ($ i = 0; $ i <count ($ ex); $ i + +)
{
echo $ ex [$ i];
}
?>
```

tanks1

Comment: You are looking for `array_unique()`. You are aware that writing variables that way `$ varname` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You could load the file into an array, using the [**`file()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function -- it'll read the file, setting one item in the array for each line of the file.

And, then, use [**`array_unique()`**](https://www.php.net/array_unique) on that array, to remove duplicates.

You'd have some code that looks like this, I suppose :

```
$list = file('./Emailist.txt');
$list_unique = array_unique($list);
foreach ($list_unique as $mail) {
    echo $mail;
}
```

Comment: I actually edited my answer to provide an example of code, at the same time he was asking for it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look at http://be.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this

```
$content = file('input.txt');
$result = array_unique($content);
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following loads the file into an array, eliminates values and prints out the array.

```
<?php
  $file = array_unique(file('emails.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
  print_r($file);
?>
```